# Strict aliasing, pointer casting and std::launder

Tags: c++, casting, strict-aliasing

I learned unfortunately too late about strict-aliasing rule and C/C++ legit dereference after cast. As far as I understand the following code does break the aforementioned rule:

```
std::byte buffer[sizeof(double)];
double* x = reinterpret_cast<double*>(buffer);

*x = 45.35;
```

Is it allowed to use `std::launder` in the following way,

```
std::byte buffer[sizeof(double)];
double* x = std::launder(reinterpret_cast<double*>(buffer));

*x = 45.35;
```

so that the code is correct? How does it affect performances?

Then, it is possible to do something equivalent in some extension of C (without using unions or `memcpy`)? Does the `-fno-strict-aliasing` option make such kind of cast safer?

Comment: I think there are other problems beside strict aliasing. `buffer` might not be aligned correctly for `double`.

Comment: both blocks of code are invalid, at least before C++20.  Not sure if the changes made in C++20 apply to this or no.

Answer (score 2):

If you had allocated the byte array via `malloc`, `operator new`, or similar functions, `launder` would not be necessary, as the result of those operations is a pointer to the created object. However, when dealing with a byte array variable directly, `launder` is needed to reach the actual object created within that array.

However, that doesn't cause the object to *exist*. And pre-C++20's implicit object creation, no object actually exists there. So your code only works under C++20's rules (which are retroactively applied to previous standards via defect reports, though only more recent compilers would be able to apply them to compilation under older standards).

Comment: Is there a way to make the code correct without using unions or memcpy?

Comment: @MaPo Yes, placement new: `double* x = new (buffer) double;`

Comment: How is `std::launder` not required here? `buffer` decays to a pointer to the first element of the `std::byte` array, which is not a `double` and `reinterpret_cast` does not result in a pointer to a `double` object because an array is not pointer-interconvertible with an object for which it provides storage.

Comment: @NathanOliver, thanks. Is there a way to mimic that in plain C or in some extension of it?

Comment: @MaPo It depends. What version of C++ are you going to use?

Comment: @NathanOliver, I was referring to C not to C++. To me C17 or C11 are ok.

Comment: @NathanOliver: Using `-fno-strict-aliasing` is far better and more reliable, since when not using that flag, both clang and gcc are prone to miscompile corner cases whose behavior is unambiguously defined by the Standard.

Comment: @MaPo: The C Standard allows implementations to, as a form of Conforming Language Extension, process code which uses pointer-based type punning as though the so-called "strict aliasing rule" did not exist., and nearly all practical C implementations can be configured to do so.  Further, most compilers which aren't configured to do so won't correctly handle all the cases defined by the Standard, so jumping through hoops to satisfy language pedants is neither necessary nor sufficient to ensure one's code will be processed meaningfully.